# Change text of the edit text by html

Tags: java

How can I do that?

```
public class ActivityTest extends Activity {

    public EditText edtText;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/htmlimages.html");
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyTest(), "Scripts");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        edtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText22);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `fromHtml` method Like this :

```
String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case to change EditText call `this.edtText.setText("What you want...")`